# How to return multiple widget in flutter ? (like review stars)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to return multiple stars with one widget but I don't know how to do that.
Exmaple: An app is rating 3/5 stars so there are 3 darkgrey stars and 2 lightgrey stars

[image]

How is it possible to send an int to a widget and return the right number of darkgrey start and lightgrey stars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Create a class:

```
class StarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int total;
  final int activated;

  const StarWidget({Key key, this.total = 5, this.activated}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: List.generate(total, (index) {
        var filled = index < activated;
        return Icon(filled ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Use it:

```
StarWidget(total: 5, activated: 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return a Row, which contains all starts.

Following code will help you more.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: callme(3),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  callme(int seleted) {
    return Row(
      children: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((e) {
        return Icon(
          e <= seleted ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the code below using:

```
StarWidget(numberOfStars);
```

Implementation:

```
class StarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int stars;
  StarWidget(this.stars);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _StarWidgetState();
}

class _StarWidgetState extends State<StarWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(widget.stars < 0 || widget.stars > 5){
      // Throw Error
    }
    List<Widget> starsList= new List();

    // Filled Stars
    for(int i = 0; i < widget.stars; i++){
      starsList.add(Icon
                    (
                      Icons.star,
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                    )
                   );
    }
    // Unfilled Stars
    for(int i = 0; i < 5 - widget.stars; i++){
      starsList.add(Icon
                    (
                      Icons.star,
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                    )
                   );
    }

    return Row(
      children: starsList,
    );
  }
}
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: You don't need `StatefulWidget` for this case.